# Execute Powershell script from php file

Tags: php, linux, powershell, active-directory

I've a powershell script that runs on Linux server and disables AD user account. The script works fine and the next step is to execute a repadmin command to sync the disabled user in all Domain Controllers (DCs). I've written following powershell script to do so:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser 
$logFile = "C:\Scripts\Log\repAdminSyncAll.txt"
$timeStamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
repadmin /syncall /APeD
Add-content $Logfile -value "$timeStamp repAdminSyncAll Script executed"
```

The script works fine if I run it in any DC, however, how can I instruct php to remote into a specific DC and execute this command?

PS. The above code&text is just an example. Ideally, I would like to execute powershell script from php/Javascript hosted on Linux server.

Comment: Why do you worry about replication?

Comment: How do you run the powershell script on the linux server?

Comment: @tukan: Natively not. But with alpha version of PS , it is possible. But the question lies on why you want to get that thing done from PHP? Are you hitting any webservice to do this? Vague questions will lead to [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta, you have logical nonsense in first two sentences (not natively vs. Alpha version is possible?). If it is alpha why to use it in any working script?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. The above was just an example. Ideally, I would like to be able to execute Powershell scripts from php/Javascript in my Linux server.

Comment: @Ravi Singh What is the reason? Do you have the DC on linux? I still do not understand your goal or motivation at all.

Comment: Hi @tukan.. DCs are in Windows. My goal is to be able to run powershell scripts (located in Windows Dcs), via php in Linux server. This is so that authenticated users (who  don't have any knowledge about powershell) can run my powershell tasks, when they need it using simple webpage.

Comment: @tukan: Why not? MS is giving full support to that. the version is 6.0.1. Dont go with the naming convention.Its possible to use PS in linux.

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta recommending running anything with alpha status on production is nonsense.

Comment: @tukan: Have you ever used it ? Tested it ? Dont talk about [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Doesnt make sense. Let him decide

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta I have not used it. I'm not talking about XY problem. From my experience using alpha, beta software for production is simply bad idea. There is a reason why the sotware is labeled alpha.

Comment: From which angle, did my language state as Beta? Go through the documentation [PS in LINUX](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and  I have already told what is the context.

Comment: @RanadipDutta In your first comment [quote]... with *alpha* version of PS , it is possible...[/quote] Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @RaviSingh To have complete understanding of your issue:  You have Windows DC and you have a linux server.  You want to interconnect the linux server accounts with Windows domain accounts?  OR  You want to have user web self-service application written in PHP (You want to have a web application which is run on your linux server to manipulate the domain accounts)?  If yes you probably misunderstood the concept, it would have to be written differently than "only" php executing a powershell script.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @RanadipDutta and tukan. Sorry, I was away from last few days, so wasn't able to reply. I've figured out the alternative, by writing an IIS service in Windows box and running my scripts by sending powershell script as CURL command from linux to Windows

Comment: @RaviSingh: Put that as an answer so that people can get the visibility of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the alternative, by writing an IIS service in Windows box and running my scripts by sending PowerShell script as cURL command from Linux to Windows.